# taking only the first iteration from a repeating array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i am printing an array in a foreach and it gives me repeated values. I just want the first set of array from it as the remaining ones are repeated sets. Can someone please help?

```
foreach($data as $data1){ print_r($new_campaign);}

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => 79.15057915057915
            [campaign  ak] => -
            [camp] => -
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => 78.52522639068565
            [campaign  ak] => -
            [camp] => -
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => -
            [campaign  ak] => NA
            [camp] => 63.74807987711214
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => 79.15057915057915
            [campaign  ak] => -
            [camp] => -
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => 78.52522639068565
            [campaign  ak] => -
            [camp] => -
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => -
            [campaign  ak] => NA
            [camp] => 63.74807987711214
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => 79.15057915057915
            [campaign  ak] => -
            [camp] => -
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => 78.52522639068565
            [campaign  ak] => -
            [camp] => -
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => -
            [campaign  ak] => NA
            [camp] => 63.74807987711214
        )

)
```

Comment: Where is your code please?

Comment: if you are fetching from db then try to handle it from query side (DISTINCT)

Comment: kindly elaborate your query and provide the code of what you have tried so far to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the proper indexes of your array variable:

```
echo $array[0]['test camp'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `$new_campaign` Array inside the foreach loop, so its repeating. call in outside loop it will  return 1 array set,

```
print_r($new_campaign);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => 79.15057915057915
            [campaign  ak] => -
            [camp] => -
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => 78.52522639068565
            [campaign  ak] => -
            [camp] => -
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [test camp] => -
            [campaign  ak] => NA
            [camp] => 63.74807987711214
        )

)
```